# Getting an exception when reading values using BOOST_FOREACH from the JSON array in C++

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I am getting the below error when reading the values using BOOST_FOREACH:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76FCB502 in JSONSampleApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::wrapexcept<boost::property_tree::ptree_bad_path> at memory location 0x00CFEB18.
```

**Could someone help me how to read values from the array with the below JSON format?**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

using namespace std;

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main()
{
const char* f_strSetting = R"({"Class": [{"Student": {"Name":"John","Course":"C++"}}]})";

    boost::property_tree::ptree pt1;
    std::istringstream l_issJson(f_strSetting);
    boost::property_tree::read_json(l_issJson, pt1);

    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type & v, pt1.get_child("Class.Student"))
    {
        std::string l_strName;
        std::string l_strCourse;
        l_strName = v.second.get <std::string>("Name");
        l_strCourse = v.second.get <std::string>("Course");

        cout << l_strName << "\n";
        cout << l_strCourse << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `BOOST_FOREACH`? Are you stuck using a pre-C++11 standard? I don't know if the issue is related to `BOOST_FOREACH`, though.

Comment: Your issue seems to be an invalid path in the ptree. Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412544/8607180

Comment: @FredLarson, I tried with C++ for loop. There also i am seeing the same issue.

Comment: Further evidence it's not related to `BOOST_FOREACH`.

Comment: You had the exact same type of question and error yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked a very similar question yesterday. We told you not to abuse a property tree library to parse JSON. I even anticipated:

> *[For more serious code you might want to use type-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70066685/unhandled-exception-when-trying-to-retrieve-the-value-from-the-json-ptree-using#:%7E:text=for%20more%20serious%20code%20you%20might%20want%20to%20use%20type-mapping)*

Here's how you'd expand from that answer to parse the entire array into a vector at once:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b024190d022019f9)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp> // for header-only
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
namespace json = boost::json;

struct Student {
    std::string name, course;

    friend Student tag_invoke(json::value_to_tag<Student>, json::value const& v) {
        std::cerr << "DEBUG: " << v << "\n";
        auto const& s = v.at("Student");
        return {
            value_to<std::string>(s.at("Name")),
            value_to<std::string>(s.at("Course")),
        };
    }
};

using Class = std::vector<Student>;

int main()
{
    auto doc = json::parse(R"({ "Class": [
            { "Student": { "Name": "John", "Course": "C++" } },
            { "Student": { "Name": "Carla", "Course": "Cobol" } }
        ]
    })");
    auto c = value_to<Class>(doc.at("Class"));

    for (Student const& s : c)
        std::cout << "Name: " << s.name << ", Course: " << s.course << "\n";
}
```

Printing

```
Name: John, Course: C++
Name: Carla, Course: Cobol
```

I even threw in a handy debug line in case you need to help figuring out exactly what you get at some point:

```
DEBUG: {"Student":{"Name":"John","Course":"C++"}}
DEBUG: {"Student":{"Name":"Carla","Course":"Cobol"}}
```

Comment: In case you prefer manual JSON traversal without the struct/vector: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af3ddd1dac30cbd5

Comment: Hi @sehe, I am using read_json with property_tree. Can you help me how to do the manual JSON traversal using read_json and property_tree ( as it is in my example).

Comment: Sure. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d444f8aaf6c611f5 (basically the same as it was in my [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70069015/85371)). Don't do this, though. And read up on the limitations of the "JSON" backend in Boost Property Tree: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser